# Does the amount of snippets installed on your MODX affect the loading speed of the frontend pages?

Tags: performance, code-snippets, modx

I'm just curious about if letting installed some snippets that are not essentials to me but handy to left installed makes sense in a common package ready to be reinstalled.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just installing them has no impact on the front end rendering speed of your pages.

You'll need to actually use them (ie. by including the snippet tag in one of your templates or resources so it is parsed by MODx) for it to affect load time.

You should cache snippets whenever possible - `[[snippet]]` instead of `[[!snippet]]` - to ensure your pages load quickly and to free up server resources.

Answer (score 2):

Having them installed doesn't affect speed, but do keep in mind that some snippets put files on the filesystem. If at some point exploits are found with those files, keeping a snippet installed that you don't use could potentially be a security risk. I haven't heard of cases like this for MODX Revolution yet, however there are a few exploits known for older versions of MODX Evolution and some of the snippets they included.